# Python Sets() behaviour

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

I am bit confused. It starts like this.

- You can add element into empty set using `add()` method.
- Sets doesn't maintain the order in which the elements are added to set.

> ```
> a=set()
> b=[4,2,3]
> for i in b:
>   a.add(i)
> ```

Expected output is `set([4, 2, 3])`

But actual output is

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python dsp.py
set([2, 3, 4])
```

So I thought/assume, **after adding element to set it got sorted** that's why output is `set([2,3,4])`.

Now, I added alphabet `'A'` to above set and output is `set(['A', 2, 3, 4])`.

To check whether this sorted or not, I created a list `b = ['A', 2, 3, 4]` and sorted it.

**Eureka !!!** Sorted list is `[2,3,4,'A']`.

So, that's why I am confused.

Requesting all to help me understand this or what I am missing.

Comment: Elements in set are not ordered , and they are not inserted in sorted order.

Comment: Sets do not preserve (initial) order.

Comment: I think this explains -- set is a data structure optimized for set operations, and like a mathematical set, it does not enforce/maintain any particular order of the elements. The abstract concept of set does no enforce order, so does not the implementation. When you create a set from a list, python takes the liberty to change the order of the elements for the needs of the internal implementation it uses for a set, which is able to perform the set operations efficiently.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre - Can I add above explanation to my question?